Notebook will no longer go into "suspend" or "sleep" mode (22.04)
after some of the regular updates on my 22.04 my ThinkPad notebook no longer suspends / sleeps (it worked before).
It seems that some of the components are powered down regularly but after a while, one components won't obey and the system returns to ON state.

Notebook will no longer go into "suspend" or "sleep" mode (22.04)
Looks like a fix was rolled out during a regular update. Works fine again without any further modifications from my side.
